# Finding the orthogonal projection of a vector on the null space of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I want to find the orthogonal projection of a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto the subspace of solutions to the linear equation $Ax=0$.

Is there a more straightforward way than determining an orthonormal basis to the null space of $A$ and then projecting $v$ onto each basis element?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a more efficient packaging of the process you describe: If $({\bf y}_1, \ldots {\bf y}_k)$ is a basis for $\ker A$, we can adjoin those vectors to form the $n \times k$ matrix $$Y := [{\bf y}_1 \cdots {\bf y_k}].$$ Then, by construction the orthogonal projection $P : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ onto $\ker A$ is
$$P = Y (Y^T Y)^{-1} Y^T ,$$
and hence the projection of $\bf v$ onto $\ker A$ is
$$P {\bf v} .$$

See these [MIT course notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf) for a derivation.

Comment: But this requires computing the basis of the kernel of $A$. If one wants to project a single vector $v$, is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming full row rank, you could project it onto the range first
$$
v_r = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}Av
$$
then substract it from the original vector to obtain the null component
$$
v_n=v-v_r
$$
or, directly from the original vector, it is
$$
v_n=(I-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A)v
$$

If inverting $(AA^T)^{-1}$ seems expensive, you could try solving
$$
Ax=0
$$
using conjugate gradient for normal equation (i.e. solving $A^TAx=0$), with $v$ as the initial value.